# Network interface with unknown speed

Tags: networking, network-interface, c

When I try to print the maximal throughput of my network interface, I receive an error:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/<interface>/speed
cat: /sys/class/net/<interface>/speed: Invalid argument
```

response. According to my investigation, this attribute is only valid for interfaces that implement ethtool `get_link_ksettings` method ([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net)).

My goal is to calculate network utilization for each interface by fetching the sent and received number of bytes each second (parsing the `/proc/net/dev` pseudo-file) and then using throughput to calculate percentage of utilization. I am doing this in C, so max throughput is obtained via `ioctl()` function that is unable to succeed for interfaces with unknown speed.

Is there a way how I can obtain the speed attribute in some other way? The simplest solution I was able to come up with is to say that the default speed of an interface is standard 10Mbps and if the utilization is over 100%, I can step the max speed up to the next standard speed of 1000Mbps and so on for 1Gbps, 2.5Gbps and 10Gbps. This could somehow work, but it may get broken with bundled interfaces utilizing non-standard speeds, e.g., two 1Gbps cards bundled into one 2Gbps. Bundled interfaces are not a big concern for me, but having general solution would be awesome.

Comment: I can give some java code to enumerate the adapters, if it can be any help

Comment: @Joe Whatever information/help I can get might be useful! Thanks.

Comment: I think the closest you can get to that information is by doing a test connection with a sustained stream of data towards a well-known server whose backbone speed is well established and known in advance, and also assuming that your unknown interface’s speed is at most not bigger than that backbone’s speed

Comment: @LL3 Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not allowed to stream data to internet to test the connection speed.

Comment: Not to internet, no, but to a local server perhaps ? I assumed you were concerning a LAN setup, what with possible 1-2-10Gbps speeds. Besides, if you’re measuring throughput to/from internet then also the `/sys/class/net/<intf>/speed` info is usually of no real use even when present and accurate. If your interface in question is of direct WAN type (e.g. an xDSL, or 4G interface) then there should be some link layer protocol (e.g. PPP) running over it, whose daemon you might try to query ?

Comment: @LL3 It depends customer to customer. Some customers have their clusters split across the whole country. So it seems like there is no way to determine the speed without actually measuring it. That is valid solution we can deal with somehow. Either disable network utilization monitoring or allow the customer to setup maximal speed per network interface manually if needed, etc. So maybe, if you are sure, you can answer the question stating that there is no way to determine network interface throughput without actually testing it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I am sure about that being the only *reliable* way to measure network *throughput*, but your question seemed to be about network interface’s *nominal speed*, which is a quite different thing

Comment: For instance, as a simple explanation, a wired ethernet interface’s nominal speed is the one negotiated between the interface itself and the switch it is directly connected to, and it is precisely the one you see from `/sys/class/net/<intf>/speed` file (when present). It commonly is either 10 or 100 or 1000 Mbps or even more, according to how the handshake procedure went between the interface and the switch, and it depends on each other’s agreeable capabilities, wire condition and length, possible EMI interference along the wires, and so on

Comment: But that does not necessarily mean that you’d have that nominal speed as actual throughput, not even towards other stations connected to the same LAN, because actual throughput must also consider overall (possibly over-)utilization of CPU/RAM/etc. resources of *both* the involved stations *and* the intermediate hop routers/switches along the path between the two stations. This becomes even more practically true when your stations go WAN, as the network throughput may suffer from inefficiencies due to equipment completely out of your control.

Comment: @LL3 Thank you for the explanation. So, to summer up and make my terminology and thoughts clear - basically the value I am looking for is the one negotiated between the two connected interfaces, e.g. networking card <-> switch. That does not mean that the card itself is not capable to throughput more data, but the speed between the two connected interfaces can reach maximally the negotiated one.

Comment: Now I am not sure how the handshake and speed negotiation works, but I am pretty sure that the card implements some standard protocol and has, in fact, negotiated the speed, but there is some problem with reporting it the operating system, i.e. the card does not implement method mentioned in my original question. Since this speeds are standardized, e.g. (in Mbps) 1, 10, 100, etc., the proposed connection utilization estimation, i.e. begin with estimation of 1Mbps and go higher if utilization exceeds 100%,

Comment: may be relatively appropriate solution of the problem as I expect that the networking speeds are scaled somehow accordingly, i.e. there will not be 1Gbps cards connected to each other if there is not a need to exceed 100Mbps. This might be not the "fits all" solution, but I guess that unability to provide negotiated speed value is not that common among networking devices and there will be even less cases where this solution would not work.